# Error using Highcharts with Vue 3 and Inertia

Tags: typescript, highcharts, vuejs3, inertiajs

I'm currently working with Vue 3 and Inertia, and I encountered an error when trying to import and use Highcharts in my project. I have attached images below to illustrate the error messages I'm receiving.

##### Error 1 (Highcharts Import):

[![Highcharts Import Error]][1]

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(vue: typeof import("D:/sites/bfc/node_modules/vue/dist/vue"), options?: ChartOptions | undefined) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Plugin<any>'.   Type '(vue: typeof import("D:/sites/bfc/node_modules/vue/dist/vue"), options?: ChartOptions | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '((app: App<any>, ...options: any) => any) & { install?: ((app: App<any>, ...options: any) => any) | ((app: App<any>, options: any) => any) | undefined; }'.     Type '(vue: typeof import("D:/sites/bfc/node_modules/vue/dist/vue"), options?: ChartOptions | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(app: App<any>, ...options: any) => any'.       Types of parameters 'vue' and 'app' are incompatible.         Type 'App<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof import("D:/sites/bfc/node_modules/vue/dist/vue")': compileToFunction, compile, defineCustomElement, useCssModule, and 146
```

##### Error 2 (Code Compilation):

[![Code Compilation Error]][2]

```
webpack compiled successfully
ERROR in ./resources/ts/app.ts:39:17
TS2345: Argument of type '(vue: typeof import("D:/sites/bfc/node_modules/vue/dist/vue"), options?: ChartOptions | undefined) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Plugin<any>'.
  Type '(vue: typeof import("D:/sites/bfc/node_modules/vue/dist/vue"), options?: ChartOptions | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '((app: App<any>, ...options: any) => any) & { install?: ((app: App<any>, ...options: any) => any) | ((app: App<any>, options: any) => any) | undefined; }'.
    Type '(vue: typeof import("D:/sites/bfc/node_modules/vue/dist/vue"), options?: ChartOptions | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(app: App<any>, ...options: any) => any'.
      Types of parameters 'vue' and 'app' are incompatible.
        Type 'App<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof import("D:/sites/bfc/node_modules/vue/dist/vue")': compileToFunction, compile, defineCustomElement, useCssModule, and 146 more.
    37 |       .use<any>(store)
    38 |       .use<any>(i18n)
  > 39 |       .use<any>(HighchartsVue)
       |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    40 |       .use(Toaster, { position: 'top-right'})
    41 |       .use(VueTheMask)
    42 |       .use(ZiggyVue)

Found 1 error in 6553 ms.
```

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Import Highcharts in a Vue 3 component.
2. Use Highcharts in the component.
3. Observe the mentioned errors during code compilation.

#### Additional Information

- Vue version: ^3.2.41
- Inertia version: ^1.0.6
- Highcharts version: ^11.2.0
- Highcharts-vue version: ^1.4.3

#### Code Snippet

Please find below the relevant code snippet where the error occurs:

```
import '@/bootstrap';
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp, Head, Link } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';
import DefaultLayout from "@/Layouts/DefaultLayout.vue";
import store from "./store";
import i18n from "@/core/plugins/i18n";
import { initInlineSvg } from "@/core/plugins/inline-svg";
import HtmlClass from "@/core/services/LayoutService";
import { initializeComponents } from "@/core/plugins/keenthemes";
import vSelect from 'vue-select'
import globalFunctions from '@/core/functions/global-functions';
import Toolbar from "@/Components/toolbars/Toolbar.vue";
import VueDatePicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker';
import '@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css';
import VueTheMask from 'vue-the-mask';
import Toaster from "@meforma/vue-toaster";
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue'


const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'EMRS';

createInertiaApp({
  title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
  resolve: async name => {
    let page =  await import(`./Pages/${name}`);
    page = page.default;
    if(page.layout === undefined){
        page.layout = DefaultLayout;
    }
    return page;
  },
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    // @ts-ignore
      createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use<any>(plugin)
      .use<any>(store)
      .use<any>(i18n)
      .use<any>(HighchartsVue)
      .use(Toaster, { position: 'top-right'})
      .use(VueTheMask)
      .use(ZiggyVue)
      .use(initInlineSvg)
      .use(globalFunctions)
      .component('Head', Head)
      .component('Link', Link)
      .component('Toolbar', Toolbar)
      .component('v-select', vSelect)
      .component('v-date-picker', VueDatePicker)
      .mount(el)
  },

})

// initialize html element classes
HtmlClass.init();
initializeComponents();

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDXkE.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN1ab.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely related to this issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue/issues/209

Currently, the `highcharts-vue` plugin is compatible with Vue 2 types, but not yet with Vue 3 types (this is currently being worked on and should be a part of the next release in the upcoming 2 weeks).

In the meantime, here's a temporary workaround you can try out:

```
// @ts-ignore
.use<any>(HighchartsVue as unknown as Plugin)
```

You can stay updated here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue

In case you'd like to manually switch out the `highcharts-vue.d.ts` file to a one compatible with Vue 3, check out this `.d.ts` that I've prepared: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue/blob/6d315fb3f0a099d21ca528bf5e4d8868479b4807/types/vue3/highcharts-vue.d.ts